# Remove duplicates in nested list with specified index

Tags: python, nested-lists

I want to remove the list which contains the maximum number( In this list 16)

Code sample

```
Lst = [["D",16],["B",10],["A",13],["B",16]]
```

required output

```
Lst =[["B",10],["A",13]]
```

Comment: i think he means occurence

Comment: My bad ill eddit my question once again

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is no sign of any effort here. Do you know how to find the maximum? Show your code. Do you know how to remove a list item or create a new list with fewer items? Show your code. What is the problem you have in doing this?

Comment: Please at least make an honest attempt to solve the problem you've given us and post it on SO, this site is not a code writing service.

Comment: I apologize for the error and it will not happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max` to get the maximum number and then filter the original list by using list comprehension:

```py
lst = [["D",16],["B",10],["A",13],["B",16]]

max_num = max(x[1] for x in lst)
output = [sublst for sublst in lst if sublst[1] < max_num]

print(output) # [['B', 10], ['A', 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Lst = [["D",16],["B",10],["A",13],["B",16]]

max_elem = -float("inf")

for element in Lst:
    if element[1] > max_elem:
        max_elem = element[1]

for i in reversed(range(len(Lst))):
    if Lst[i][1] == max_elem:
        Lst.pop(i)

print(Lst)
```

Comment: `max` is a built-in function name in python. It is not recommended to name your variables with a built-in keyword.

Comment: @AlveMonke I agree, I have fixed it

Comment: max is a built-in function, so you should use it.